# create a custom 404 page

Tags: symfony, http-status-code-404

I am new in symfony and I want to generate or create a custom 404 page when a route is not found.

here is the error I get :

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function getDestinationURL() on a non-object in /home/smiles/Downloads/prototype/redirect-app/src/GS/RedirectBundle/Controller/RedirectController.php line 247
```

the redirect function :

```
    public function redirectAction($source)
{        
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $repository = $em->getRepository('GSRedirectBundle:Redirect');
    $redirect = $repository->findOneBySourceURL($source);
    $destination_url = $redirect->getDestinationURL();
    return $this->redirect($destination_url);
}
```

what can I do ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting means that $redirect variable is null - no entity was found with such source url.

You could do global error page http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html but you could also solve it with checking if entity was found or not, which is really crucial in cases like this, for example:

```
public function redirectAction($source)
{        
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $repository = $em->getRepository('GSRedirectBundle:Redirect');
    $redirect = $repository->findOneBySourceURL($source);
    if (null == $redirect) {

        return $this->redirect('my_resource_not_found_route');
    }
    $destination_url = $redirect->getDestinationURL();

    return $this->redirect($destination_url);
}
```

Comment: I made another code similar. if (!$redirect)
        {
                        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Redirect entity.');
} thx anyway

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a file app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/error.html.twig and there you can put the customized error page.

You can find more info at http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html .

Comment: have you cleared your symfony's cache? `rm app/cache/* -rf` ? Do you check it on prod or dev env?

Comment: what var_dump($redirect) shows ? just below the $redirect declaration?

Comment: i am working in the dev mode, is it true that this onlz works on prod mode ?

Comment: yes, it is. because there is prepared one another page for dev to show more details.

Comment: @bouraxwebmaster You should fix the parse error regarding `getDestinationURL` before working out a custom 404 page. The issue is your redirect is not firing because that method does not exist and you are getting a 500.